# Why does my Java StringTokenizer read emptyspace?

Tags: java

I wrote this program that should only break down the string when there is greater than sign or a colon. When I enter for example "cars:ford>  chevy" , the output gives me the space between the > and "chevy" and then the word "chevy. How do I prevent it from giving me that white space? All I want is the word , here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class wp{
    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter words");

        String ingredients = keyboard.nextLine();

        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(ingredients,">:");

        while(str.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println(str.nextToken());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the space is part of the input, it is valid that the tokenizer returns it (think of situations where you want to react to the space).

So  all you need to do is postprocess your split results e.g.:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter words");

        String ingredients = keyboard.nextLine();

        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(ingredients, ">:");

        while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String nextToken = str.nextToken();
            String trimmed = nextToken.trim();
            System.out.println(trimmed);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to trim is ok also, but on line

```
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(ingredients, ">:");
```

you specified delimiters as characters `'>'` and `':'`, you can simply add space there too. It depends what your requirements are. If you want for string `"cars:ford> chevy 123"` to have 4 tokens, this is what you have to do...

So change it to

```
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(ingredients, ">: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`trim()` method of String class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) to remove all preceding and succeeding white spaces: 
`str.nextToken().trim()`.